# Boost 1.65.1 geometry::buffer can't use

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I'm using `boost::geometry::buffer`, but compiler errors happen, here is my code and compiler errors:

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>

void test2()
{
  using Point = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
  using Polygon = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point>;

  Polygon mp;
  Polygon mp_result;
  boost::geometry::append(mp, Point(0.1, 0.1));
  boost::geometry::append(mp, Point(0.1, 1.1));
  boost::geometry::append(mp, Point(1.1, 1.1));
  boost::geometry::append(mp, Point(1.1, 0.1));
  boost::geometry::buffer(mp, mp_result, 1.1);
}

int main()
{
  test2();
  return 0;
}
```

Partial compilation error：

```
/usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/buffer.hpp:127:55: error: ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘boost::geometry::dispatch::buffer<boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> >, boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> >, boost::geometry::polygon_tag, boost::geometry::polygon_tag>’
         dispatch::buffer<Geometry, GeometryOut>::apply(geometry, distance, chord_length, out);
```

The example is very simple, but I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: [rtfm](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html), Geometry bugfixes section.